# SQL Select removing characters from a column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need a "replace" select query that strips everything but 3 characters after a string.

Example:

```
Data = "CN=GOT002086,OU=LAPTOPS,OU=COMPUTERS,OU=GOT,DC=CORP,DC=GDS,DC=COMPANYNAME,DC=COM"
```

I need to replace the output of this field to only show "GOT".  I figured I could key on the word "COMPUTERS" within the column and if possible select only the 3 characters 4 spaces after the word "COMPUTERS".  This column is a fully qualified computer name and I only want the OU to be shown.

Comment: you would probably have to tell us in which DB system you do it and if you use any client code. For Sql Server looks like combination of `PATINDEX` and `SUBSTRING` should be sufficient.

Comment: so, do you need data that comes after `COMPUTERS,OU=` and befor the next comma? Like this `COMPUTERS,OU=??????,`. And the data is variable but this time it is `GOT`, correct

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
DECLARE @TestString VARCHAR(1000)
SET @TestString = 'CN=GOT002086,OU=LAPTOPS,OU=COMPUTERS,OU=GOT,DC=CORP,DC=GDS,DC=COMPANYNAME,DC=COM'
SELECT SUBSTRING(@TestString, CHARINDEX('COMPUTERS,', @TestString ,0)+13,3)
```

### Updated

```
CREATE TABLE ActualValuesTable (ValueColumn VARCHAR(250))

INSERT INTO ActualValuesTable VALUES('CN=GOT002086,OU=LAPTOPS,OU=COMPUTERS,OU=GOT,DC=CORP,DC=GDS,DC=COMPANYNAME,DC=COM')
INSERT INTO ActualValuesTable VALUES('CN=GOT002086,OU=LAPTOPS,OU=COMPUTERS,OU=123,DC=CORP,DC=GDS,DC=COMPANYNAME,DC=COM')
INSERT INTO ActualValuesTable VALUES('SomeText..OU=COMPUTERS,OU=789,SomeText..')
INSERT INTO ActualValuesTable VALUES('SomeText..OU=COMPUTERS,OU=012,SomeText..')
INSERT INTO ActualValuesTable VALUES('SomeText..OU=COMPUTERS,OU=234,SomeText..')
INSERT INTO ActualValuesTable VALUES('SomeText..OU=COMPUTERS,OU=456,SomeText..')


SELECT SUBSTRING(ValueColumn, CHARINDEX('COMPUTERS,', ValueColumn ,0)+13,3) FROM ActualValuesTable
```

Comment: Thank you    This will work for the single row, but I have an entire column to screen out. So I cannot specify just this row, I need to somehow say SHOW the OU after OU=COMPUTERS. Does that make sense?

Comment: I have given that code for just to show how it can be done.If you want I can give you complete script to work out. give me some time.

Comment: Thanks classic_vmk, yes please take your time.